# Get Post Insights for multiple posts in one call using Graph Api 2.7

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get post insights for a page feed using Facebook Graph API version 2.7 ..

If I only write:

```
'[Page ID]/feed?fields=insights'
```

It asks for metric, which indicates it should work... But when specifying a metric:

```
'[Page ID]/feed?fields=insights/post_impressions/lifetime'
```

I get syntax error.

I've tried with . notation as:

```
'[Page ID]/feed.insights/post_impressions/lifetime'
```

But stil no luck!

I know I can do it post by post (separate calls to API), but that is what I'm trying to avoid.

Anyone know what the correct syntax is for nested insights?

Comment: _"Anyone know what the correct syntax is for nested insights?"_ - AFAIK there isn't one. Field expansion is not available for all endpoints yet. You could try and request the insight metric for several posts at once, via the [`?ids=` syntax](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#multiidlookup). If you want it for the x most recent posts, you could do a batch request, that gets the post ids from the feed endpoint first, and then requests the metric for those ids.

Comment: Ok..  I hope field expansion for that endpoint comes out soon. Meanwhile, I'll go with one of those options.

Thanks @CBroe!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This bug report was able to shed some light: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1755454881375647/

You can use the `metric` keyword to specify the metrics you want, like so:

```
/page-id/posts?fields=insights.metric(post_impressions,post_consumptions_unique)
```

Name the metrics you are interested in there, and separate them with a comma.

Specifying the period (where applicable) seems to work by the same kind of syntax,

```
/…?fields=insights.metric(…).period(lifetime)
```

(Although it might not work to request different periods for different metrics in one go.)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.. THANKS!

Comment: A straightforward explanation that should be found on the API documentation - thanks.