# Facebook api 2.7 - No Metric Specified

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been using below request to receive data from facebook api:

```
143357502355510/feed?fields=insights{name,title}&since=1474732800&until=1477324800&limit=100
```

but after version 2.6 has been deprecated and I changed sdk version to 2.7 this error is receiving:

```
"error": {
"message": "Invalid query",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 3001,
"error_subcode": 1504028,
"is_transient": false,
"error_user_title": "No Metric Specified",
"error_user_msg": "No metric was specified to be fetched. Please specify one or more metrics to be fetched and try again.",
"fbtrace_id": "XXXXXXXXXXX"
}
```

anyway to change the request and get the same data as before?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the answer here:

[check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39104504/5246647)

and I changed my request to:

```
143357502355510/feed?fields=insights.metric(post_impressions_unique,post_impressions){values,title}&since=1474732800&until=1477324800&limit=100
```